# comments_number fails to print

Tags: categories, comments, template-tags

I want to display the number of comments on a post using the template tag

```
            <?php comments_number( $zero, $one, $more ); ?>
```

However, for some reason this tag does nothing and it is not printed to the page. You can view an example of what I mean at http://blog.diginomics.com/bitcoins-innate-regulation/

Here is the full snippet of code for the 3 template tags: author, category, and comment:

```
                    <div class="post-info">
                    <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ); ?>" class="post-item">
                        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                        <?php the_author(); ?>
                    </a>

                    <a href="<?php get_category_link( $category_id ); ?>" class="post-item">
                        <i class="fa fa-tags"></i>
                        <?php the_category( '&bull;' ); ?>
                    </a>                            

                    <a href="<?php comments_link(); ?>" class="post-item">
                        <i class="fa fa-comments"></i>
                        <?php comments_number( $zero, $one, $more ); ?>
                    </a>
                </div>
```

Why are the comment numbers not showing, and as a side question, why is the category split into 2 sections and not styling as it should?

Comment: The below 2 answers worked well. Thank you guys. I am also wondering why my category tag is separated like it is and why is it not styling like the other tags?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use it for comment number `<?php comments_number( 'no responses', 'one response', '% responses' ); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use this function in **loop**.

"Displays the total number of comments, Trackbacks, and Pingbacks for the current post. This tag must be within The Loop."

And also you will need to use this.

```
<?php comments_number( '0', '1', '%' ); ?>
```

Replace it with yours `<?php comments_number( $zero, $one, $more ); ?>`